# Two firebase onSnapShot() calls but only 1 of them is working even though its the same code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a class that loads in data during construction and sets the initial state of two variables, itemsPrayer, and itemsNews. This works fine. Then I have a getData() method where I call the same firebase firestore collections and I use onSnapShot() so I can receive instant changes.

The itemsPrayer works just fine, as soon as I type a new message it gets output to the window, but when I type a new message for itemsNews, I have to refresh the component manually in order to see the new comment.

My thought is, am I able to have two onSnapShots()?

```
export class Landing extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tab: 0,
      isDesktop: false,
      form: false,
      bottom: false,
      viewPopup: true,
      itemsPrayer: Array.from(
        db.collection("prayerRequest").orderBy("created", "asc").get()
      ),
      itemsNews: Array.from(
        db.collection("upliftingStories").orderBy("created", "asc").get()
      ),
    };
    this.updatePredicate = this.updatePredicate.bind(this);
    // this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
  }

  // componentDidUpdate() {
  //   this.getData();
  // }

  getData = () => {
    db.collection("prayerRequest")
      .orderBy("created", "asc")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        let chat = this.state.itemsPrayer;
        let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
        changes.forEach((change) => {
          if (change.type === "added") {
            chat.push({ ...change.doc.data() });
          }
        });
        this.setState({ itemsPrayer: chat });
      });

    db.collection("upliftingStories")
      .orderBy("created", "asc")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        let chat = this.state.itemsNews;
        let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
        changes.forEach((change) => {
          if (change.type === "added") {
            chat.push({ ...change.doc.data() });
          }
        });
        this.setState({ itemsNews: chat });
      });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
    this.updatePredicate();
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updatePredicate);

    if (window.location.reload) {
      this.setState({ viewPopup: true });

      setTimeout(
        function () {
          this.setState({ viewPopup: false });
        }.bind(this),
        8000
      );
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updatePredicate);
  }

  updatePredicate() {
    this.setState({ isDesktop: window.innerWidth > 410 });
  }

  togglePopup() {
    this.setState({ form: true });
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const isDesktop = this.state.isDesktop;

    const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
      this.setState({ tab: newValue });
    };

    let window = this.state.tab ? (
      <WindowUplifting items={this.state.itemsNews} />
    ) : (
      <WindowPrayerRequest items={this.state.itemsPrayer} />
    );

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        {isDesktop ? (
          <Tabs
            value={this.state.tab}
            onChange={handleChange}
            variant="fullWidth"
            aria-label="simple tabs example"
            className={classes.tabs}
            style={{ backgroundColor: "#000000" }}
          >
            <Tab style={{ color: "#ffffff" }} label="Prayer Requests" />
            <Tab style={{ color: "#ffffff" }} label="Uplifting Stories" />
          </Tabs>
........
```

I tried this code based on a comment but the same thing happens,

```
componentDidMount() {
    const prayer_query = db
      .collection("prayerRequest")
      .orderBy("created", "asc");

    const news_query = db
      .collection("upliftingStories")
      .orderBy("created", "asc");

    //
    prayer_query.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      let chat = this.state.itemsPrayer;
      let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
      changes.forEach((change) => {
        if (change.type === "added") {
          chat.push({ ...change.doc.data() });
        }
      });
      this.setState({ itemsPrayer: chat });
    });

    news_query.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      let chat = this.state.itemsNews;
      let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
      changes.forEach((change) => {
        if (change.type === "added") {
          chat.push({ ...change.doc.data() });
        }
      });
      this.setState({ itemsNews: chat });
    });
```

Comment: if you remove the listener of  `prayerRequest`, is the listener of the collection `upliftingStories` working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

`onSnapshot()` works like an event listener for changes to firestore documents. Typically, you will put these methods in the `componentDidMount` method of a React component instead of putting them as a function on its own, to get the intended result you achieve.

You can add snippets of `onSnapshot()` in a format like this.

```
  //Initialise change object
    let new_change_object = {};

    //Listeners
    prayer_query.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      let chat = this.state.itemsPrayer;
      let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
      changes.forEach((change) => {
        if (change.type === "added") {
          chat.push({ ...change.doc.data() });
        }
      });
      new_change_object["itemsPrayer"] = chat;
    });

    news_query.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      let chat = this.state.itemsNews;
      let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
      changes.forEach((change) => {
        if (change.type === "added") {
          chat.push({ ...change.doc.data() });
        }
      });
      new_change_object["itemsNews"] = chat;
    });

    this.setState(new_change_object);
```

Comment: Aqil, In my code above, that function getData() is inside the componentDidMount so it is getting called. I did just try your idea though, creating the const variables and moving everything inside componentDidMount instead of it being in its own function and the same result happens. Only 1 of the onSnapshots() gets updated.

Comment: @bsnow Could you try writing the exact snippet of code you've tried on an edit to your post or maybe in the comment?

Comment: @bsnow I have edited my answer to fix your solution. You have `setState` too many times. Try to keep it once as it is also expensive to re-render so many times.

Comment: That doesn't work either, using that code, now both of the components don't get updated automatically instead of the original one not updating.